# How to wrap span around ul li but not in Child ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, parent

How can I affect the `ul.menu li a` elements only, and not child elements (`ul.submenu li a`)?

Here is my code:

```js
$('ul.menu li a').wrap('<span></span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">I want the span</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">I want the span</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Don't want the span</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Don't want the span</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Don't want the span</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">I want the span</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">I want the span</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`child`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector rather than just the [`descendant`](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) selector:

```
$('ul.menu > li > a').wrap('<span></span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dyev5/

Comment: Thanks for the faster and correct answer :), I'm only try with $("ul.menu > li a").wrap("<span />"); ..